# Row Not Updating

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, api, datatable

I am trying to update a row in a datatable using editable cells. It works to update on the interface but the data does not go into the api and after I reload the page the modification dissapear.

```
function buildlist() {
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sarcini-list/';
  fetch(url).then(
    res => {
      res.json().then(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          var table
          const createdCell = function(cell) {
            let original;
            cell.setAttribute('contenteditable', true)
            cell.setAttribute('spellcheck', false)
            cell.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
              original = e.target.textContent
            })
            cell.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
              if (original !== e.target.textContent) {
                const row = table.row(e.target.parentElement);
                $.ajax({
                  type: "PUT",
                  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sarcini-detail/' + row.data().idSarcina,
                  data: row.data()
                })
                console.log('Row changed: ', row.data())
              }
            })
          }
          table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
            columnDefs: [{
              targets: '_all',
              createdCell: createdCell
            }],
            scrollX: true,
            data: data,
            columns: [
              { data: 'idSarcina' },
              { data: 'nr_tren' },
              { data: 'nr_locomotiva' },
              { data: 'plecare' },
              { data: 'ora_plecare1' },
              { data: 'ora_sosire1' },
              { data: 'angajat1' },
              { data: 'angajat2' },
              { data: 'schimb1' },
              { data: 'ora_plecare2' },
              { data: 'ora_sosire2' },
              { data: 'angajat3' },
              { data: 'angajat4' },
              { data: 'schimb2' },
              { data: 'ora_plecare3' },
              { data: 'ora_sosire3' },
              { data: 'angajat5' },
              { data: 'angajat6' },
              { data: 'sosire' },
              { data: 'ora_plecare4' },
              { data: 'ora_sosire4' },
              { data: 'angajat7' },
              { data: 'angajat8' }
            ],
          });
        }
      )
    }
  )
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  buildlist();
});
```

I modified the field "NUMAR TREN" and as you can see in the console in the api the change does not take place but in the interface it looks ok.

[This is how it looks in console and interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjGc4.png)